# If $Y_1, Y_2$ are exponential random variables, how can I find $P(Y_1 <Y_2)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have that $Y_1, Y_2$ are independent exponential random variables with rate parameter $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ respectively, how can I find $P(Y_1<Y_2)$? I know that I am supposed to use the integral but cannot get the joint distribution. Thanks.

Comment: ist there any relationship between the too?

Comment: I can't get the joint distribution either. But if you tell me the $Y_i$ are independent then I can.

Comment: They are independent, sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\Pr(Y_1<Y_2) = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(Y_1<Y_2\mid Y_1)) = \operatorname{E}(e^{-\lambda_2 Y_1}) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_2 y_1} \Big( e^{-\lambda_1 y_1} (\lambda_1\,dy_1) \Big).
$$

Or, if you prefer:
$$
\Pr(Y_1<Y_2) = \int_0^\infty \Pr(y_1<Y_2) e^{-\lambda_1 y_1} (\lambda_1\,dy_1) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_2 y_1} \Big( e^{-\lambda_1 y_1} (\lambda_1\,dy_1) \Big).
$$

Comment: I've never seen that first equality before -- what's it called, and why does it work? Reminds me of the tower property a bit

Comment: @Nitin : It's the law of total probability, although that term is used in different ways.  There is a law of total expectation (google it) and there is a law of total variance.  The latter breaks the total variance into explained and unexplained components. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Nitin : The law of total probability can be stated as $\Pr(A) = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(A\mid X))$, where $X$ is a random variable.  Say for example $X$ can be equal to either $x_1$ or $x_2$.  Then $\Pr(A\mid X=x_1)$ and $\Pr(A\mid X=x_2)$ are just simple conditional probabilities.  And then $\Pr(A\mid X)$ is a random variable, equal to $\Pr(A\mid X=x_i)$ with probability $\Pr(X=x_i)$ for $i=1,2$.  So the identity says $\Pr(A) = \Pr(A\mid X=x_1)\Pr(X=x_1) + \Pr(A\mid X=x_2) \Pr(X=x_2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy So basically in the first equality, what you did was take $E(I_{Y_1<Y_2}) = P(Y_1 <Y_2)$ and then use $P(Y_1 <Y_2) = E(I_{Y_1<Y_2}) = E(E(I_{Y_1<Y_2}|Y_1)) =  E(P(Y_1 <Y_2 | Y_1))$, where $I_{Y_1<Y_2}$ is an indicator random variable?

Comment: @user136503 : Certainly it can be looked at that way. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

You want to integrate over the region $Y_1<Y_2$:

$$P(Y_1<Y_2)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{y_2}\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 y_1}\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y_2} \, dy_1 \, dy_2.$$

This is relatively straightforward to evaluate. The answer should be

$$\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.$$

Comment: Do you know why you have a double integral? Normally my understanding of the formula is: $\Pr \left[ X < Y \right] = \int \Pr \left[ X < y \right] f_Y \left( y
   \right) \mathrm{d} y = \int F_X \left( y \right) f_Y \left( y \right)
   \mathrm{d} y$ thanks!

Comment: @user136503: It's equivalent, since $F_X(y)=\int_0^y f_X(t)dt$.

Comment: I am unconvinced that your numerator in the bottom line should be $\lambda_2$ rather than $\lambda_1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The one with the higher rate is more likely to be smaller than the other one, so the probability that $Y_1$ is smaller should get bigger as $\lambda_1$ gets bigger.  Hence the numerator should be $\lambda_1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks, I stupidly thought the mean is $\lambda$ and performed the exact same analysis :).

Comment: The argument to $x\mapsto e^x$ must be a number, not a number times a unit of measurement.  So if $\lambda$ is measured in units per minute and $y$ in minutes, then $\lambda y$ can be the argument to that function.  The average value $\alpha$ of something measured in the units in which $y$ is measured (often _time_) must be in those same units, so $y/\alpha$ is unitless and can be the argument to the exponential function.