# Find $P(X>Y)$ if $X,Y$ are independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability, multiple-integral

Let $ X,Y $ be two independent exponential random variables with means $ 1 $ and  $3$, respectively. Find  $P(X>Y)$.

I know $F(X,Y)$ is $\iint 3e^{-x-3y}\,dx\,dy$. But I'm confused on the limits of $P(X>Y)$.

Comment: You should have said something like: "I know that the probability/integral asked for is ..." It is totally unclear what you mean with $F(X,Y)$. The uppercase $F$ smells like a CDF, but that is contradicted again by the fact that the arguments $X,Y$ are random variables.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233955/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2561014/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571684/321264

Answer (score 2):

It helps to draw a picture of the plane, and draw the region containing points $(x,y)$ such that $x<y$.

> In the end, either $\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty \cdots \, dx \, dy$ or $\int_0^\infty \int_0^x \cdots \,dy \, dx$ will workwork.

Answer (score 2):

We want $x\ge y$ for the integral, and $y$ should range from $0$ to $\infty$. So the integral is
$$\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}e^{-x-\frac{1}{3}y}\, dx \, dy.$$

(I realised the PDF you wrote was incorrect because we are told the *means*. If an exponential random variable has mean $\beta$, then its PDF is $\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}$ (for $x \ge 0$).)

Comment: How did you get the double integral? Is it from the definition of PDF for continuous random variables?

Comment: To get a probability like this, we integrate the joint PDF $f(x,y)$ over the region corresponding to the event, which in this example is the region $\left\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : y > 0 \text{ and } x > y\right\}$. To integrate over this region, if you draw a diagram of the region in the $x$-$y$ plane, you can see that $y$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$ (the outer integral), and for any fixed $y > 0$, we have $x$ vary from $y$ to $\infty$ (the inner integral). Therefore, the integral we want is equal to $$\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=y}^\infty f(x,y)\, dx \, dy.$$

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not completely okay. It assumes that $\lambda=3$ (this on base of the integral that was mentioned in the question) while actually $\lambda=\frac13$. The idea is the same, though and I have decided to leave it like this. See the answer of Minus One-Twelfth (who observed the mistake and edited) for a correct version.

---

Let $\chi(x,y)$ take value $1$ if $x>y$ and take value $0$ otherwise.

Then here:

$$P(X>Y)=\mathbb E[\chi(X,Y)]=\int\int\chi(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty}3e^{-x-3y}dxdy$$

---

edit (I could not resist the comment)

$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}3e^{-x-3y}dxdy & =3\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3y}\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{-x}dxdy\\
 & =3\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3y}\left[-e^{-x}\right]_{y}^{\infty}dy\\
 & =3\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3y}e^{-y}dy\\
 & =3\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-4y}dy\\
 & =3\left[-\frac{1}{4}e^{-4y}\right]_{0}^{\infty}\\
 & =\frac{3}{4}
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: on intragrating this $P(X>Y)=\mathbb E[\chi(X,Y)]=\int\int\chi(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty}3e^{-x-3y}dxdy$ the question gives the value is  $e^(-3y)$  then what is the value of y

Comment: I edited the way how to do it. Check me on mistakes, though.

Comment: i got the answer this  1-P(X<Y) =1-0.75=0.25

Comment: I see now that the *mean* of $Y$ is $3$ which means that its parameter is $\lambda=\frac13$. That is the source of the mistake. $0.25$ is correct if $\lambda=\frac13$ and $0.75$ would have been correct if $\lambda=3$.

Comment: thanks brother you help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$f_X(x) = e^{-t}, f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{3}e^{-\frac{y}{3}}$$
Hence $$P(Y \lt y) = F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_Y(y^\prime) dy^\prime = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{3}e^{-\frac{y^\prime}{3}} dy\prime = 1 - e^{\frac{y}{3}}$$
So
$$P(X>Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t} f_X(t) f_Y(y) dydt = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_X(t)P(Y \lt t)dt$$ $$= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}(1-e^{-t/3})dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}-e^{-4t/3}dt=1/4$$