# Calculate the probability that the exponential random variable $X$ is greater than the exponential random variable $Y$?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two independent random variables X and Y with exponential probability distributions with two rates $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$, respectively. Also, we have $\lambda_x>\lambda_y$. How can the following probability be calculated?

$P(X>Y)?$

can i write as follows?

$P(X>Y)=\int_0^\infty P(X>Y|Y=y)dy=\int_0^\infty P(X>y)dy$

Comment: A little searching goes a long way: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2561014/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233955/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571684/321264

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence between the 2 rv's and assuming that the specified parameters are "rate" parameter you get

$$\mathbb{P}[X>Y]=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda_x e^{-\lambda_x x}\left[\int_0^x \lambda_y e^{-\lambda_y y}  dy \right]dx$$

Comment: can i write as follows? $P(X>Y)=\int_0^\infty P(X>Y|Y=y)dy=\int_0^\infty P(X>y)dy$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: What is the joint distribution of $X,Y$ assuming their independence?

Hint 2: What is the region in $X,Y$ space where $X>Y$? Can you integrate the join probability over it?